# Implementing Array.Except(Array2) > 0 query in elasticsearch filter?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Let's say I have following documents indexed:

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Numbers": [1, 2, 3]
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Numbers": [4, 5]
    }    
]
```

I have a parameter [1,2,4,5], which defines which numbers I am not allowed to see - I want to find documents where "Numbers" array contains at least one element NOT in my input array (so in this case first document should be returned).

Real scenario is for finding groups which (or who's child groups) do not contain products belonging to certain product type. I have recursively indexed product type ids (represented as numbers in the example) and I want to find groups which contain products not belonging to my input parameter (my input parameter being an array of product type ids I am not allowed to see)

Which query/filter should I use and how should it be constructed? I have considered the following:

```
        return desc.Bool(b => b
            .MustNot(mn => mn.Bool(mnb => mnb.Must(mnbm => mnbm.Terms(t => t.ItemGroups, permissions.RestrictedItemGroups) && mnbm.Term(t => t.ItemGroupCount, permissions.RestrictedItemGroups.Count())))));
```

but the problem is if I have 6 restricted item groups, where as a given group contains 3 restricted groups, then I won't find any matches because the count won't match. That makes quite a bit of sense now. As a workaround I've implemented Results.Except(Restricted) in C# to filter out restricted groups post-search, but would love to implement it in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**New answer**

I'm leaving the older answer below as it might be of use to other people. In your case, you want to filter out documents that don't match and not only flag them. So, the following query would get you what you expect, i.e. only the first document:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          // copy the doc values into a temporary list
          def tmp = new ArrayList(doc.Numbers.values);

          // remove all ids from the params
          tmp.removeIf(n -> params.ids.contains((int)n));

          // return true if the array still contains ids, false if not
          return tmp.size() > 0;
        """,
        "params": {
          "ids": [
            1,
            2,
            4,
            5
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Older answer**

One way to solve this is by using a script field which will return true or false depending on your condition:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "_source": true,
  "script_fields": {
    "not_present": {
      "script": {
        "source": """
      // copy the numbers array
      def tmp = params._source.Numbers;

      // remove all ids from the params
      tmp.removeIf(n -> params.ids.contains(n));

      // return true if the array still contains data, false if not
      return tmp.length > 0;
""",
        "params": {
          "ids": [ 1, 2, 4, 5 ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result would look like this:

```
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "Id" : 2,
          "Numbers" : [
            4,
            5
          ]
        },
        "fields" : {
          "not_present" : [
            false                           <--- you don't want this doc
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "Id" : 1,
          "Numbers" : [
            1,
            2,
            3
          ]
        },
        "fields" : {
          "not_present" : [
            true                            <--- you want this one, though
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm interesting, any idea how how much it would effect performance? I imagine it could get pretty extreme with millions of documents?

Answer (score 1):

The [`terms_set` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html) seems like a good fit for this; it's similar to a `terms` query with the additional distinction that you can specify how many of the terms must match with a dynamic value either derived from the input or each document.

In your case, you want to get the inverse of documents where all the numbers in the `Numbers` array are in the input terms i.e. if the `Numbers` array contains at least one value that is not in the input terms, then it should be considered a match.

Something like the following would work

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var defaultIndex = "my_index";
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
        .DefaultFieldNameInferrer(f => f);

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

    var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
        .Settings(s => s
            .NumberOfShards(1)
            .NumberOfReplicas(0)
        )
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<MyDocument>(mm => mm.AutoMap())
        )
    );

    var bulkResponse = client.Bulk(b => b
        .IndexMany(new []
        {
            new MyDocument { Id = 1, Numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }},
            new MyDocument { Id = 2, Numbers = new int[] { 4, 5 }},
            new MyDocument { Id = 3, Numbers = new int[] { }},
        })
        .Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor)
    );

    var searchResponse = client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
        .Query(q => (!q
            .TermsSet(ts => ts
                .Field(f => f.Numbers)
                .Terms(1, 2, 4, 5)
                .MinimumShouldMatchScript(sc => sc
                    .Source("doc['Numbers'].size()")
                )
            )) && q
            .Exists(ex => ex
                .Field(f => f.Numbers)
            )
        )
    );
}

public class MyDocument 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int[] Numbers { get; set; }
}
```

The generated search request looks like

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "Numbers"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "terms_set": {
            "Numbers": {
              "minimum_should_match_script": {
                "source": "doc['Numbers'].size()"
              },
              "terms": [
                1,
                2,
                4,
                5
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and the result is

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "mydocument",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "Id" : 1,
          "Numbers" : [
            1,
            2,
            3
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The `terms_set` query is in a `must_not` clause to invert matches where all values in `Numbers` are in the terms input, and is combined with an `exists` query on `Numbers` to exclude documents that have no values for `Numbers`, as in the example document with Id 3.

This could be made to perform better by also indexing the length of the `Numbers` array in another field in the document, then using `MinimumShouldMatchField(...)` instead of the script. Just need to make sure that the two properties then remain in sync, which would be fairly easy to do in a C# POCO with a property getter that returns the `Numbers` array length value.

Comment: Hmm interesting, thanks. I'll have to take a look at this. One thing I didn't mention though is that we are running ES .17, so termsSet doesn't seem to be available yet.

Comment: `terms_set` is only available in Elasticsearch 6.1.x onwards. If you're on 0.17, you may want to consider upgrading to take advantage of many new features, performance improvements and bug fixes